# Cannot locate sent solana from ledger to coinbase

Tags: transactions, transfer, send-transaction, missing

So I sent some solana from my ledger to my coinbase and now it’s missing, the address match exactly except the address I sent it to is in all lowercase anyway to revive my funds since it’s the correct address just in lower case ?

Comment: Can you post the transaction?

Comment: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2iHPaoxuj5WnS8DmvDUKqDzdp6x3Heo5drKuLbxFNXwMfYMNJvtkKxMtVFsqk455WmSHYNjPd8PyqaEhck49KLJH